# C++ undefined constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, undefined

I am just starting out with C++, and ran into this problem. I have a class Fifo defined in Fifo.h:

```
/* Fifo.h */
#ifndef FIFO_H_
#define FIFO_H_

#include <atomic>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

template <class T>
class Fifo
{
public:

   Fifo<T>(int len);
   ~Fifo<T>();

   int  AddTokens(T* buffer, int len);
   int  RetrieveTokens(T* buffer, int len);

private:
   //int len;

};

#endif /* FIFO_H_ */
```

And the definitions in Fifo.cpp:

```
/* Fifo.cpp*/
#include "Fifo.h"

template <class T>
Fifo<T>::Fifo(int len)
{
  //_fifoptr = new FifoImpl_class((T)len);
  printf ("From the constructor\n");
  //thisbuffer = malloc(sizeof(T)*len);
}


template <class T>
Fifo<T>::~Fifo() { }

template <class T>
int Fifo<T>::AddTokens(T* buffer, int len)
{
  printf("Added tokens\n");
  return(1);
}


template <class T>
int Fifo<T>::RetrieveTokens(T* buffer, int len)
{
  printf("Removed tokens\n");
  return(2);
}
```

And, I test my class like this (Fifotest.cpp):

```
#include "Fifo.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Fifo<int> MyFifo(20);
}
```

Building it with gcc-4.5 gives me this error:
undefined reference to `Fifo<int>::~Fifo()'
undefined reference to`Fifo::Fifo(int)'

Looks like I have the relevant methods defined, but I am not able to figure out why I get this error. I spent time googling for it, and the option was to take a running class and modify it. But then, I want to know what is wrong with what I already have. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: This must have six trillion dupes.

Answer (score 2):

[If you put template definition in cpp file, the definitions will not be available outside that cpp file.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12)
When you include `Fifo.h` from `Fifotest.cpp`, the compiler sees the declaration of your template class, but it does not see the implementation of the methods. Once you move them to the `Fifo.h` header, everything should compile.

Comment: Well, you can. You can put whatever you like wherever you like. C++ doesn't give a monkeys what your file extensions are. It just causes errors in most scenarios when you use the conventional inclusion idiom.

Comment: I think you missed my point. There are plenty of scenarios where it will work just fine. That you wrote the definition in "a cpp file" is not the critical issue; that the definition is not visible to other TUs is. Causally linked, yes, but not equivalent!

Answer (score 2):

2 points:

- The constructor is declared erroneously.

  ```
  Fifo<T>(int len); //wrong
  Fifo(int len);    //right
  ```
- Templates should be defined in the same translation unit in which they are used, so having separate .h and .cpp files usually doesn't work for templates(see, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)). Please move the contents of your cpp file to the header file and you should be fine.

Comment: Actually, I'm fairly sure that they're both correct- `Fifo<T>` and `Fifo`. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Me too. `Fifo` in that context is a synonym for `Fifo<T>` and there's no template ctor being declared. But I didn't try it either.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, Fifo is indeed a synonym for Fifo<T> but it is an injected class name which means it's as though a public member of the base class. So I'm inclined to believe you can't declare a constructor like that (I may be wrong though)

Comment: Note though that this [won't work in an out-of-line _definition_](http://codepad.org/vyfV9RTn), because then the `template <typename T>` prelude tries to make the ctor a function template, which obviously cannot work.

Comment: @Tomalak: You did what? We aren't talking about whether a particular implementation supports it. We are thinking whether is it allowed standardwise

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Now I did try it, quite obviously. OK, so it's not a standards proof, but it's not bad... and it lends more credibility to your being wrong than to your being right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636094/is-it-valid-to-write-the-template-types-parameter-list-in-a-constructor-declara

Comment: @Tomalak: LOL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636098/can-the-declaration-of-a-constructor-of-a-class-template-include-template-argume

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for help. I included "Fifo.cpp" in "Fifo.h", as was discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file. Well, obviously, having the implementation also in the header file seems like a very bad design practice, since I would not like to share my implementation. To this end, I read up the PIMPL technique, which may answer, but so far, I have had no luck in having neatly separated header and implementation, and templates put together. Any nice tutorials?

Comment: @devendrarai: Sorry, but there's just no good way to avoid sharing the implementation in case of templated. There are some workarounds but they aren't universal and are a real pain in the ass. Just accept that in case of generic code you'll have to share your implementation

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the definitions in the header file. `export` keyword exists in the standard but usual compilers haven't implemented it.