# Is it valid to write the template type's parameter list in a constructor declaration?

Tags: c++, templates

Old GCC 4.1.2 [accepts](http://codepad.org/vlxxxHJX), and new GCC 4.5.1 [accepts](http://www.ideone.com/8sFjl), the following program.

But is it actually correct? What does the standard say about declaring a constructor with the type's template parameter like this?

<sup>(I find it interesting that I'm not allowed to [do the same in the out-of-line definition](http://codepad.org/vyfV9RTn).)</sup>

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   Foo<T>(); // <---
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo() {
  std::cout << ":)";
}

int main() {
   Foo<int> f;
}
```

<sub>The reason I ask is that it was proposed in comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635981/c-undefined-constructor/8636007#8636007) that GCC may be in error here.</sub>

Comment: FWIW, builds & runs on GCC 4.6.1 too.

Comment: Presumably due to 12.1/1: "The syntax uses... the constructor's class name...", this question amounts to "is `Foo<T>` the class name?"

Comment: @SteveJessop: ... "and, if so, why isn't it accepted in the definition?"

Comment: @Tomalak: yes indeed. I don't see how it can be the name (or anyway one version of the name) in one scope but not the other, so this certainly looks wrong to me, I'm just short of the references to prove it. The standard does prohibit using a `typedef` alias in place of the name, so it's certainly not just a case of "any identifier that resolves to the class is OK".

Comment: @SteveJessop: 14.6.1/1 'Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injectedclass-
name can be used as a template-name or a type-name. ...' So it the class name not be a template_id, but the template name, I think.

Comment: perhaps you also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/4420839/34509

Comment: @SteveJessop the question is, is it the "name" in the sense of "a name that names that class" or "an identifier in the form of the name used in the class' class-head". Later the spec forbids typedef-names "used as the class-name", which to me means that with "the constructor's class name" it means any name that denotes the class (otherwise it wouldn't have to concern with typedefs at all). Also if it would just be "any identifier matching that form", it would not do name lookup, and would not find typedef names in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will put a mail copy of a possible DR I recently sent out on Christmas here

> Is the following code well formed?
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> struct A {
>   A<T>();
> };
> ```
>
> The several compilers that I tested (clang, g++ and comeau conline)
>   accept this. Indeed 12.1 does not forbid this (`A<T>` is a name of that
>   class and is not a typedef-name), but 8.3p1 says
>
> *An unqualified-id occurring in a declarator-id shall be a simple
>   identifier except for the declaration of some special functions (12.3,
>   12.4, 13.5) ...*
>
> A constructor is a special member function, but the list of cross
>   references does not include 12.1. Does that mean that the above code
>   is ill-formed? Or is this an accidental omission?

If you do the same in an out-of-line definition, you will try to pass template arguments to a constructor. This is valid code

```
struct A {
  template<typename T> A();
};

template<> A::A<int>() { }
```

The spec says that when the injected class name is used in a qualified name when looking into the scope of the class (just as in `A::A`), then when name lookup accepts function/constructor names, the injected class name reference will be translated to be resolved to the constructor(s) of that class (if the name lookup context only accepts types, then the name will remain the injected class name, and will denote the class type). After `A::A`, name lookup is complete and yields the constructor. The `<int>` can then only be parsed as a template argument list. If there is no template among your constructors, your code will be invalid.

Comment: The first paragraph seems to imply that given code is valid.  But errr... the OP asked about a regular constructor of a template class, not about a templated constructor.   ( `A<T>::A()` i.s.o. `A::A<T>()` ).

Comment: @xtofl I think you misunderstood my answer. After the copy of my mail, I elaborated on the part of OP's question "(I find it interesting that I'm not allowed to do the same in the out-of-line definition.)". The first paragraph (the quote representing my mail) does imply that the code is accepted by GCC, clang and the comeau online compiler. It does not imply that the code is valid.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm a clever guy, but can you summarise this for me?

Comment: @tomalak the summary is: don't do it, it is not clear whether it is formally allowed, and the committee hasn't decided yet.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I shouldn't have written 'imply'.  My point was that I think you elaborated on the template function `template<class T> A::A<T>`, while OP asked about the constructor declaration `A<T>::A` (in response of mentioned question, which _uses_ this notation to _declare Fifo's constructor_.

Comment: @xtofl i showed an example why it makes sense to interpret `<T>` as a template argument list. As I said "Whether <int> is taken as a template argument list or not is independent of whether A::A is a function template or not.". Since he has a non-template constructor, and uses a template argument list, his code is ill-formed. It would be hard to believe that his code is ill-formed for that reason if there is no code that benefits from the semantics, hence my example.

Comment: The main reason though, IIRC, was a parsing difficulty - that you now can specialize such constructors without function arguments was just a nice side effect. But since I'm not fond on the parsing difficulties, I don't talk about them.

Comment: More precisely, it is *not* taken as template argument list if there is no template, but since there is no less-than expression allowed here, there is no alternative path, so a parsing error occurs. The compiler is clever and recovers interpreting the `<T>` as a template argument list. I updated my answer to correctly reflect the semantics.